# EJB_JAR - Problem with my xml validating against the xsd

Tags: java, ejb

I am working with EJB for the first time and I am defining the ejb-jar.xml file. The problem is that I am getting an error that says: "cvc-id.3: A field of identity constraint 'ejb-name-key' matched element 'ejb-jar', but this element does not have a simple type."

The xml that I am using is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar id="EJBJar_1234567890" version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
  metadata-complete="false">
<enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven>
        <ejb-name>ClassIRefere</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>xx.xx.xx.ClassIRefere</ejb-class>
         <activation-config>
         <activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
            <activation-config-property-value>xx/xx/xx/Whatever</activation-config-property-value>
         </activation-config-property>
         <activation-config-property>
           <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
           <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Topic</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
           <activation-config-property-name>subscriptionDurability</activation-config-property-name>
           <activation-config-property-value>Durable</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
           <activation-config-property-name>clientId</activation-config-property-name>
           <activation-config-property-value>xxxxx</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
           <activation-config-property-name>user</activation-config-property-name>
           <activation-config-property-value>xxxx</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
           <activation-config-property-name>password</activation-config-property-name>
           <activation-config-property-value>xxxx</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
           <activation-config-property-name>subscriptionName</activation-config-property-name>
           <activation-config-property-value>xxxxx</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
      </activation-config>
    </message-driven>
</enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

I searched for the error and it should mean that the ejb-name element is not unique, but it is. I dont know what else to do rigth now. I would appreciate any help.

I tried to modify the name in case my project had any similar name. Nothing. I tried to add another mesage driven with two ejb-name, each one unique. Nothing. I tried to create a new xml file because this one was copied from another project just in case there was any problem with it. Nothing.